# ACFS replication file type support | SAS, .sas,.csv files

Tags: oracle

Does ACFS  and ACFS replication support SAS files ? such as .sas .csv files, is there any list for
which of the file types ae supported by ACFS and ACFS replication?

Answer (score 1):

ACFS is a Unix-Like filesystem so any file stored in Primary site will be replicated to the Standby site.

You can use this one as reference:
[ACFS Replication](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/cloud-storage/acfs-replication-12-2010-279867.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

ACFS replicates a complete file system hence all supported files on an ACFS file system will get replicated.

Thanks